# How can I automatically change directory on ssh.exe login?

Tags: windows, openssh

I'm trying to get ssh.exe to open an ssh session in the specific direrecory on the remote server.

my command: `ssh.exe root@1.1.1.1 -p 22 "cd /home && bash"`
it works, but I didnt got login message and the `root@1.1.1.1:~#` prefix

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3acn1.png)

Answer (score 0):

solved with replace `&&` to `\;`
my final batch (maybe)

```
@echo off
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe --title %6 ssh %3 -p %4 -t "cd %5 \; bash --login"
```

Comment: the only problem is the not fixed title.
i mean it changes title to "OpenSSH SSH client" when ssh session starts.

Comment: found a way, a `--suppressApplicationTitle` arg does what I was looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).